# Connection established to google DNS, can't resolve any hosts

Tags: domain-name-system

[image: wadingooo]

As you can see from the picture above, I am connected to google DNS but am unable to resolve any hostnames.  When I try to ping sites like google.com, yahoo.com, etc, I get 'ping: unknown host'.

Yes, I am able to ping localhost, I am able to ping hostname.domain.com, but not domain.com.
I can't ping my nameservers.  I can ping all hosts by IP address and that works.  The output of my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Anyone know what the problem could be?

```
23:30:04.304955 IP my_server.44457 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 28349+ A? google.com. (28)
23:30:06.137985 IP 112.100.0.78.19781 > my_server.domain: 18717 [1au] A? www.my_domain.com. (46)
 23:30:06.138286 IP my_server.domain > 112.100.0.78.19781: 18717*- 2/0/1 CNAME my_domain.com., A my_server (76)
23:30:06.686582 IP 112.100.0.74.19181 > my_server.domain: 65046 [1au] A? my_domain.com. (42)
23:30:06.686811 IP my_server.domain > 112.100.0.74.19181: 65046*- 1/0/1 A my_server (58)
23:30:07.043764 IP my_server.50465 > 4.2.2.1.domain: 13865+ PTR? 142.254.22.67.in-addr.arpa. (44)
23:30:09.065904 IP my_server.45242 > 8.8.4.4.domain: 29011+ PTR? 123.72.117.130.in-addr.arpa. (45)
23:30:09.310021 IP my_server.45440 > 8.8.4.4.domain: 28349+ A? google.com. (28)
```

Comment: Have you taken a packet capture?

Comment: Try ping google.com.  (note dot at the end)

Comment: updated with packet capture

pinging google.com. with dot at the end gives same results

Comment: possible duplicate of [ping: unknown host google.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/397572/ping-unknown-host-google-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem within an interface configuration file.  There were no other DNS entries besides localhost.